# Bot crashing from pyautogui

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, pyautogui

I am making a bot that makes the chrome dinosaur jump every time it sees a cactus.

The RGB for the cactus is (83,83,83)

I made a specific coordinate for my code to look at, and check if the RGB of that pixel matches the cactus (jump_place)

However, when I run it, it works for about 2 seconds, and then gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\dofia\OneDrive\Desktop\coding VS\Other Projects\DINO BOT\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 29, in <module>
    if pyautogui.pixel(810, 635)[0] == 83:
  File "C:\Users\dofia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 584, in pixel
    return (r, g, b)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\contextlib.py", line 124, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\dofia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 113, in __win32_openDC
    raise WindowsError("windll.user32.ReleaseDC failed : return 0")
OSError: windll.user32.ReleaseDC failed : return 0
```

Here is my code:

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random

time.sleep(3)


replay = (1127,591) 
jump_place = (866,630)
  

def restart():
    pyautogui.click(replay)

def jump():
    pyautogui.keyDown('space')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("Jump!")
    pyautogui.keyUp('space')

restart()
while keyboard.is_pressed('p') == False:
    if pyautogui.pixel(810, 635)[0] == 83:
        jump()
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

The link to the dinosaur game is: **http://www.trex-game.skipser.com/**